# Basic Probability: Bag with either of two possibilities, add a third, probability of a certain outcome?

Tags: probability

Hi I'm currently taking a basic probability course and ran into a problem of this sort.

**The problem:**

I have a bag that contains either a red marble or a blue marble, each with probability 0.5.
Next, I add a red marble into the bag so the bag now contains two marbles in total.

After the bag is shaken, I draw a marble and discover that it is red (x1).

What is the probability that the remaining marble is also red (x2)?

**My attempt so far:**

According to the conditional probabilities, I can write something like:
$$
P(x_2 = red|x_1=red) = P(x_2=red \cap x_1 =red)/P(x_1=red)
$$
where x1 and x2 are the individuals draws.

I see that the probability that  since at least one marble HAS to be red (having put it in afterwards) and the the chance that the other marble is red is 0.5 as stated:
$$
P(x_2=red \cap x_1 =red) = 0.5
$$

What I'm having trouble with is the probability of the first marble being red. I'm tempted to say that the probability is 0.75, but I'm not sure if that would be correct or how to justify that.

Comment: Isn't it the same as the probability of there being $2$ red marbles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
there are two cases, each with probability 0.5:

- both marbles are red: $P(x_1 = red | case1) = 1$
- only the one you added is red: the probability is then: $P(x_1 = red | case2) = 0.5$